# How to create columns from a list of values

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
Table 1
Row   ID     Value        Cost
1     1      Priority 1   10,000
2     2      Priority 2   9,000
3     3      Priority 3   8,000
4     4      Priority 4   6,000

Table 2
Row   Name    Priority   Cost
1     Jon     1          10,000
2     Bob     3          8,000
3     Dan     4          7,000
4     Steve   2          9,000
5     Bill    3          8,000
...
```

I want the table to look like this:

```
Table 3
Row  Name     Priotity 1     Priority 2     Priority 3     Priority 4
1    Jon      10,000
2    Bob                                    8,000
3    Dan                                                   7,000
4    Steve                   9,000
5    Bill                                   8,000
...
```

How can I create rows from Table 1 as columns, and fill in the output as shown in Table 3.

I am hoping this is not as basic as it sounds, but my SQL is terrible!

Comment: Google:  "<database name> dynamic pivot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this for dynamic pivot table.

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)


SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(Value as varchar) + ']',
'[' + cast(Value as varchar)+ ']')
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Value

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)
SET @query = 'with Priorites as
(select a.Name,b.Value,b.Cost from Table2  a left join Table1 b on a.Priority =b.id)
SELECT *
FROM Priorites 
PIVOT
(
MAX(Cost)
FOR [Value]
IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Here is the link for more details http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php

Answer (score 0):

`Pivot` is always useful in this sort of scenario, but if the actual data is as simple as it's in question (like there are only 4 unique `Priority` and/or only `1` Priority is assigned to a particular user),then you can achieve this task with following query:

```
  select t.row,t.name
  (case when t.priority = 1 then t.cost
        else ' '
   end
  ) as Priority1,
  (case when t.priority = 2 then t.cost
        else ' '
   end
  ) as Priority2,
  (case when t.priority = 3 then t.cost
        else ' '
   end
  ) as Priority3,
  (case when t.priority = 4 then t.cost
        else ' '
   end
  ) as Priority4
 From
  (select Row,name,priority,cost
  from Table2
  group by name) t
 group by t.name;
```